# conditions in clojure to build a string and update a variable

Tags: loops, clojure, multiple-conditions

I thought I'd tryout clojure, doing a puzzle printing a path from start to target.
My attempt is printing nothing.

I understand i've written this in a procedural way, but am not sure the best way to thinking about writing this functionally.  So I'd like to understand why this prints nothing, how to have a condition execute 2 actions (ie: add the direction to the string and update the position.  All the examples I found online only execute 1 action), as well as how to actually make this work.  Ideally, how to make my approach work, and also what would be the ideal clojure approach.

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (def x 2)
  (def y 3)
  (def t_x 10)
  (def t_y 15)
  (while true
    (let [m ""]
      (cond
        (> y t_y) (let [m (str m "N")])(- y 1)
        (< y t_y) (let [m (str m "S")])(+ y 1)
        (> x t_x) (let [m (str m "W")])(- x 1)
        (< x t_x) (let [m (str m "E")])(+ x 1))

      ; A single line providing the move to be made: N NE E SE S SW W or NW
      (println m)))))
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you do `(while true ...)` where is the exit condition? where is the condition when the loop should break/end?

Comment: Good point.  In the situation I was using it, the puzzle engine watched to see when the solution was found, but the end condition would be x==t_x  && y==t_y

Comment: Thanks I figured that out (see my answer) - after translating your code I realized it has an endpoint - when using `loop`-`recur` - but a `(while true ...)` needs definitely a condition to test for break out.. (it is when actually none of the listed clauses are called (and nil is returned which brings the `loop`-`recur` loop to stop. I think the last solution with `recur` uses Clojure's peculiarities the best.

Comment: To all of you who left answers to this question, I learned more from reading your examples than I did from reading the docs for days.  Thank you.  There should be more clojure docs with examples like this.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than use loops or recursion, this solution uses [sequences](https://clojure.org/reference/sequences), a prevalent abstraction in Clojure:

```clj
(defn axis-steps [a b axis axis']
  (concat
    (cond
      (< a b) (repeat (- b a) axis)
      (< b a) (repeat (- a b) axis'))
    (repeat nil)))

(defn path [x y tx ty]
  (let [ns (axis-steps y ty "S" "N")            ; = ("N" "N" nil nil nil ...)
        ew (axis-steps x tx "E" "W")            ; = ("E" "E" "E" nil nil nil ...)
        nsew (map str ns ew)                    ; = ("NE" "NE" "E" "" "" "" ... )
        steps (take-while seq nsew)]            ; = ("NE" "NE" "E")
    (clojure.string/join " " steps)))           ; = "NE NE E"
```

```clj
(path 2 3 10 15) ; => "SE SE SE SE SE SE SE SE S S S S"
```

Comment: how does clojure deal with the unknown number of nil at the end of ns?

Comment: Clojure sequences are _lazily realized_. This means that elements are produced from the sequence on demand. In my answer, `ns`, `ew` and `nsew` are infinitely long sequences, but `steps` is a finitely long sequence, so the `join` works as expected.

Comment: The `map` function (I prefer `mapv`) will truncate all input sequences to the length of the shortest one.  Also, the `str` function will translate a `nil` to the empty string. This confused me greatly trying to write my 1st Cloure program, and it is not my favorite trick by a longshot!.

Answer (score 3):

1. First of all, you want to treat the variables like mutable variables. Variables in Clojure are not modifiable like that. Except you declare them as `atoms`. `atom`s are special mutable variables.
2. `(while true ...)` is very un-clojure-ish and very `C-ish`. Use `(loop [ ... ] ...)` in combination with `recur`. But for that you have to understand the syntax of `loop` and `recur`.
3. Your `(let [m (str m "N")])` the let form closes before doing anything. The local assignment `[m (str m "N")]` is only valid until the `let` form closes s- between the `]` and the last `)`. You do `(- y 1)` after the closed let.
   And this is the case in all following `cond` clauses.
   Finally you do `(println m)` which, since it is within the `(let [m ""]` form, would then print the `""`.

To Clojure atoms, the documentation is [here](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/while)
it lists as example:

```
;; a var to be used for its side effects
(def a (atom 10))                                
;; #'user/a

(while (pos? @a)
  (println @a)
  (swap! a dec))
;; 10
;; 9
;; 8
;; 7
;; 6
;; 5
;; 4
;; 3
;; 2
;; 1
;;=> nil
```

However, as an imperative programmer, one thinks in terms of `a = new_value`. where it is better then to use `(reset! a new-value-of-a)`. Because `swap!` misled me also totally at the beginning.
Let's say you want to do `a = a + 1`. Then you have to think okay what function is there which does:
`a = func(a)`? - it would be `inc`. then `a = a + 1` is equivalent to `(swap! a inc)`. => this set's `a` to `(inc a)`. But let's say youw ant to increase by more than just 1, let's say by 3. Then you hav eto give `inc` also the addiional argument in addition to `a`. Let's say you want `a` to be set to `(inc a 3)`. Then this swap! call would look like: `(swap! a incf 3)`.

So you have to declare all your variables (`x`, `y`, `m`) as atoms in this way. And use either `swap!` (or for the beginner easier `reset!` to update their values. Eventually, you have to use even references, when access to the mutable variable should be thread-safe.

#### Solution using recursive loop by `loop [variables] <actions> recur)`

Ah but I see this is not a games situation - but just some process running itself.

For this case, I translated your attempt into a recursive loop.

```
(loop [x 2
       y 3
       tx 10
       ty 15
       m ""]
  (println m)
  (cond (< ty y) (recur x (- y 1) tx ty (str m "N "))
        (< y ty) (recur x (+ y 1) tx ty (str m "S "))
        (< tx x) (recur (- x 1) y tx ty (str m "W "))
        (< x tx) (recur (+ x 1) y tx ty (str m "E "))))
```

It prints:

```
S 
S S 
S S S 
S S S S 
S S S S S 
S S S S S S 
S S S S S S S 
S S S S S S S S 
S S S S S S S S S 
S S S S S S S S S S 
S S S S S S S S S S S 
S S S S S S S S S S S S 
S S S S S S S S S S S S E 
S S S S S S S S S S S S E E 
S S S S S S S S S S S S E E E 
S S S S S S S S S S S S E E E E 
S S S S S S S S S S S S E E E E E 
S S S S S S S S S S S S E E E E E E 
S S S S S S S S S S S S E E E E E E E 
S S S S S S S S S S S S E E E E E E E E 
;; => nil
```

Now I see, your `t_x` and `t_y` were the target coordinates.

for `SE`, `NE` etc. such combined movements, you have to introduce clauses which tests for them e.g.
`(and (< y ty) (< x tx))  (recur (+ x 1) (+ y 1) tx ty (str m "E "))` and other such clauses.

As I see, `tx` and `ty` are not changing ever. So put them out of the `loop`-`recur` loop:

```
(let [tx 10 ty 15] 
  (loop [x 2
         y 3
         m ""]
    (when (not= m "") ; print only when m is not an empty string
            (println m))
    (cond (and (< ty y) (< x tx)) (recur (+ x 1) (- y 1) (str m "NE "))
          (and (< y ty) (< x tx)) (recur (+ x 1) (+ y 1) (str m "SE "))
          (and (< ty y) (< tx x)) (recur (- x 1) (- y 1) (str m "NW "))
          (and (< y ty) (< x tx)) (recur (- x 1) (+ y 1) (str m "SW "))
          (< ty y) (recur x (- y 1) (str m "N "))
          (< y ty) (recur x (+ y 1) (str m "S "))
          (< tx x) (recur (- x 1) y (str m "W "))
          (< x tx) (recur (+ x 1) y (str m "E ")))))
```

It prints:

```
SE 
SE SE 
SE SE SE 
SE SE SE SE 
SE SE SE SE SE 
SE SE SE SE SE SE 
SE SE SE SE SE SE SE 
SE SE SE SE SE SE SE SE 
SE SE SE SE SE SE SE SE S 
SE SE SE SE SE SE SE SE S S 
SE SE SE SE SE SE SE SE S S S 
SE SE SE SE SE SE SE SE S S S S
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the explanations.

Answer (score 3):

what i would propose, is to make the lazy sequence of `[dx dy]` steps towards the end. Something like this:

```
(defn path [curr end]
  (when-not (= curr end)
    (lazy-seq
     (let [delta (mapv compare end curr)]
       (cons delta (path (mapv + delta curr) end))))))

user> (path [2 3] [10 15])
;;=> ([1 1] [1 1] [1 1] [1 1] [1 1] [1 1] [1 1] [1 1] [0 1] [0 1] [0 1] [0 1])
```

so the next thing you need is to translate everything to human-readable directions:

```
(defn translate [[dx dy]]
  (str ({-1 \S 1 \N} dx)
       ({-1 \W 1 \E} dy)))

user> (map translate (path [2 3] [10 15]))
;;=> ("NE" "NE" "NE" "NE" "NE" "NE" "NE" "NE" "E" "E" "E" "E")

user> (map translate (path [10 15] [3 21]))
;;=> ("SE" "SE" "SE" "SE" "SE" "SE" "S")

user> (map translate (path [10 15] [3 3]))
;;=> ("SW" "SW" "SW" "SW" "SW" "SW" "SW" "W" "W" "W" "W" "W")
```

Comment: Wow this is very terse! And very Clojure-ish.

Comment: I thought of using `compare`, but thought it might be a bit too "tricky" to spring on a beginner.  I do very much like the idea of a two stage solution, calculating the "delta steps" in stage 1, then translating into string headings in stage 2.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would write it, using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) & library:

```
(ns demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core))

(defn next-x
  [x x-tgt]
  (cond
    (< x x-tgt) {:x (inc x) :dir "E"}
    (> x x-tgt) {:x (dec x) :dir "W"}
    :else {:x x :dir ""}))

(defn next-y
  [y y-tgt]
  (cond
    (< y y-tgt) {:y (inc y) :dir "N"}
    (> y y-tgt) {:y (dec y) :dir "S"}
    :else {:y y :dir ""}))

(defn update-state
  [pos pos-goal]
  (let [x-info     (next-x (:x pos) (:x pos-goal))
        y-info     (next-y (:y pos) (:y pos-goal))
        pos-next   {:x (:x x-info) :y (:y y-info)}
        dir-str    (str (:dir y-info) (:dir x-info))
        state-next {:pos-next pos-next :dir-str dir-str}]
    state-next))

(defn walk-path [pos-init pos-goal]
  (loop [pos pos-init]
    (when (not= pos pos-goal)
      (let [state-next (update-state pos pos-goal)]
        (println (:dir-str state-next))
        (recur (:pos-next state-next))))))
```

and some unit tests to show it working:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (is= (next-x 0 5) {:x 1, :dir "E"})
  (is= (next-x 6 5) {:x 5, :dir "W"})
  (is= (next-x 5 5) {:x 5, :dir ""})

  (is= (next-y 0 5) {:y 1, :dir "N"})
  (is= (next-y 6 5) {:y 5, :dir "S"})
  (is= (next-y 5 5) {:y 5, :dir ""}))

(dotest
  (is= (update-state {:x 0, :y 0} {:x 1, :y 1}) {:pos-next {:x 1, :y 1}, :dir-str "NE"})
  (is= (update-state {:x 1, :y 0} {:x 1, :y 1}) {:pos-next {:x 1, :y 1}, :dir-str "N"})
  (is= (update-state {:x 2, :y 0} {:x 1, :y 1}) {:pos-next {:x 1, :y 1}, :dir-str "NW"})
  (is= (update-state {:x 0, :y 1} {:x 1, :y 1}) {:pos-next {:x 1, :y 1}, :dir-str "E"})
  (is= (update-state {:x 1, :y 1} {:x 1, :y 1}) {:pos-next {:x 1, :y 1}, :dir-str ""})
  (is= (update-state {:x 2, :y 1} {:x 1, :y 1}) {:pos-next {:x 1, :y 1}, :dir-str "W"})
  (is= (update-state {:x 0, :y 2} {:x 1, :y 1}) {:pos-next {:x 1, :y 1}, :dir-str "SE"})
  (is= (update-state {:x 1, :y 2} {:x 1, :y 1}) {:pos-next {:x 1, :y 1}, :dir-str "S"})
  (is= (update-state {:x 2, :y 2} {:x 1, :y 1}) {:pos-next {:x 1, :y 1}, :dir-str "SW"}))
```

and the final result:

```
(dotest
  (let [pos-init {:x 0 :y 0}
        pos-goal {:x 3 :y 5}
        str-result (with-out-str
                     (walk-path pos-init pos-goal))]
    ; (println str-result)  ; uncomment to print result
    (is-nonblank= str-result
      "NE
       NE
       NE
       N
       N")))
```

There is still some obvious duplication in the functions `next-x` & `next-y` that could be consolidated, and `update-state` could be cleaned up a little, but I wanted to keep it simple to start w/o using more advanced features or helper functions.

---

For reference, please see [this list of documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), especially the Clojure CheatSheet and the book "Getting Clojure"

Regarding your questions:

1. `(< y y-tgt) {:y (inc y) :dir "N"}` -
   Clojure usually uses "keywords" instead of strings to name the fields in a map.  In source code, these have a single colon at the front, instead of a pair of quotes.
2. `pos-next {:x (:x x-info) :y (:y y-info)}` - Correct. The return value is a new map with keys `:x` and `:y`, which are copied from the maps in the variables `x-info` and `y-info`
3. Think of a `loop` statement as similar to a `let` block. The first symbol of each pair defines a new "loop variable", and the 2nd symbol of each pair is the initial value of that variable.
   Since there is only 1 pair, there is only 1 loop variable and hence only 1 value in the `recur` statement.
   A `loop/recur` form can have zero or more loop variables.

Comment: (< y y-tgt) {:y (inc y) :dir "N"}   -    :y  and  :dir  are creating property names in the returned object?   Are the colons regular clojure, or the template project?

Comment: pos-next   {:x (:x x-info) :y (:y y-info)}     -    
 :y (:y y-info)  is saying use the :y value from y-info  and assign it to the :y value in pos-next?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. It took me some time to mentally parse this.  With  (recur (:pos-next state-next) it has 1 argument.  Does this know to update pos in loop[pos pos-init] because it is the first argument? (I've seen some examples where they give 2 arguments to recur)